# How does it check the line of sight between two points? Any clarification to this implementation below please?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path-finding

I am a beginner of Python, developing myself on the one hand and trying to finish my project on the other hand. I'm trying to work with an algorithm for path finding that checks the line of sight between two points, below is an implementation of this algorithm, but I couldn't understand the behavior of this code very well.

The code is for the line of sight algorithm to check between two points if they are visible to each other or not. Any clarification please for its work? Could I get a clarification for the code, please?

```
grid = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
#start, goal = (0,0),(4,3)
start, goal = (0,0),(4,3)

def los(start, goal):
    x0, y0 = start
    x1, y1 = goal

    dy = y1 - y0
    dx = x1 - x0

    if dy < 0:
        dy = -dy
        sy = -1
    else:
        sy = 1

    if dx < 0:
        dx = -dx
        sx = -1
    else:
        sx = 1

    f = 0
    result = []

    if dx >= dy:
        while x0 != x1:
            f = f + dy

            if f >= dx:
                result.append((x0+(sx-1)/2, y0+(sy-1)/2))
                y0 = y0 + sy
                f = f - dx
            if f != 0:
                result.append((x0+(sx-1)/2, y0+(sy-1)/2))
            if dy == 0:
                a = (x0+(sx-1)/2, y0)
                b = (x0+(sx-1)/2, y0-1)
                result.extend((a, b))
            x0 = x0 + sx
    else:
        while y0 != y1:
            f = f + dx

            if f >= dy:
                result.append((x0+(sx-1)/2, y0+(sy-1)/2))
                x0 = x0 + sx
                f = f - dy
            if f != 0:
                result.append((x0+(sx-1)/2, y0+(sy-1)/2))
            if dx == 0:
                a = (x0, y0+(sy-1)/2)
                b = (x0-1, y0+(sy-1)/2)
                result.extend((a, b))

            y0 = y0 + sy
    return result


check = los(start,goal)
print(check)
```

Comment: Bresenham's line algorithm is a good place to start, it seems like your method is loosely based on it. It's for drawing lines between 2 points on a 2d grid but can be extended for LOS calculations

Comment: @lain Shelvington is it having the same work?